# View the change history of a file using github.com

Tags: git, github

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278192/view-the-change-history-of-a-file-using-git-versioning) about using the command line, but is it possible to view the file change history of a single file in a repository on github.com?

An in-browser solution would help me to better illustrate changes to team members while in meetings.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can view the change history of a file by clicking on the history button, or by adding `commits` to the URL of the file. Here is what it looks like for a file at the [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29) repository on GitHub:

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commits/master/SUPPORTERS.md

To get a line-by-line history, simply add the [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) string of the commit for which you want to see the diff to the URL after the word `commit`, and then anchor it with the filename you are interested in. For the same file above:

*https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commit/288f001e924d5365b79c279e4478f372a04011ae#SUPPORTERS.md*

To see **all** commits for a **single** branch use a URL like this

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commits/master

To see **all** commits for **all** branches use a URL like this

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commits

There is no button or link in the web UI for these URLs, but you can bookmark them easily.

Comment: I'm probably just blind, but where's this "history" button?

Comment: I think this answer is outdated.  I've tried the second link example and the adding anchor `#filename` is totally useless now, Github would show all files' differ no matter whether you adding a `#filename` or not.

Comment: Are you talking about the [GitHub Desktop application](https://help.github.com/en/desktop/contributing-to-projects/viewing-the-branch-history)? In any case, perhaps update your answer?

Comment: @jozxyqk , "history" is not a button, it's clickable text.  Today (2020-10-30), I found it on the right-edge of the screen about 4-inches down from the address bar, with icon of a clock rotating backwards next to it.

Comment: If anybody misses the `History` button, they may want to try a Tampermonkey script that adds GitLab's-like `History` button on GitHub pages: https://gist.github.com/foka/881a73313348927d547420101259abda

Answer (score 20):

As @BurhanKhalid say, but here explaining as a "GitHub fast guide", with URL syntax:

1. Browse your project at `https://github.com/<USER>/<PROJECT>` ...
2. ... then you have a URL ending with the file path: `https://github.com/<USER>/<PROJECT>/blob/master/<PATH>`
3. Now you have all, is only to change "blob/master" to "commits/master": `https://github.com/<USER>/<PROJECT>/commits/master/<PATH>`

PS: to remember "commits/master" click at the project's home in the "Commit" link.

Ops: there are [a similar answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952507/can-github-show-the-history-of-changes-made-to-one-file-in-patch-form/2952551#2952551), @TimHenigan expressed with `http://github.com/<username>/<project>/commits/<branch>/<path/to/file>`

---

### Question to GitHub developers team

Why do you not offer a direct link for this kind of browsing? We need it, like Wikipedia readers need "history" link!

---

Ops, GitHub's team is listening to us?

Now (June 2014) when you browse through the folders, an icon appears, see "browse commits" above right. When you click, the `tree/master` URL turns `commits/master`.

**Still missing to have the same for files**, as showed here, but was an evolution.

Answer (score 14):

I think [git-history](https://github.com/pomber/git-history) is an alternative and good method for quickly browsing the history of files in any Git repository.

You don't need to download anything. You only need to replace the domain in the URL.

Steps to do:

1. Go to a file in **GitHub** (or **GitLab**, or **Bitbucket**)
2. Replace `github.com` with `github.githistory.xyz`

There are [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/git-history-browser-exten/laghnmifffncfonaoffcndocllegejnf) and [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/github-history/) extensions to add an `Open in Git History` button on GitHub, GitLab and Bitbucket so that you don't need to memorize step 2.

For more information, you can go to its [GitHub page](https://github.com/pomber/git-history).

Comment: This should really be at the top, since OP was looking for a GUI tool (as was I), and this has the added benefit of not needing to click into each commit, and then take additional steps to diff against the previous change

Answer (score 11):

The GitHub capabilities for history exploration for a file just got a bit better in Apr. 2021 with:

> ### "[View file at a specific point in the commit history](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-04-30-view-file-at-a-specific-point-in-the-commit-history/)"

> When viewing the commit history of a single file, users can now click to view that file at the selected point in history.
>
> [image: https://i1.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/16675781/116747128-c01edc00-a9fd-11eb-9009-008305786885.gif?ssl=1 -- view history]

From there, type "<kbd>b</kbd>" for the blame view of that file in that commit, and [explore its changes](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/tracking-changes-in-a-file):

> With the blame view, you can view the line-by-line revision history for an entire file, or view the revision history of a single line within a file by clicking [image: before].
>
> Each time you click [image: before], you'll see the previous revision information for that line, including who committed the change and when.
>
> [image: Git blame view]

Comment: That "view at this point in history" button was what I was looking for to get line-by-line differences for a single file. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As of , if you want to view **all the change records in a easy way** on GitHub, **NO**, I did not find an easy way to do that **in browser**.

How you view one commit change history on GitHub:

1. You visit any file, let's say `hello.cpp` on GitHub, click the "history" button, then you can see the commits that change this file.
2. Then by clicking each commit's "sha" button, you see the whole commit.
3. Then you find `hello.cpp`, click "view file" button. And finally you only see the difference of
   this commit `-` last commit.

So if you want to look through all the history changes, you have to repeat the process above for so many times.. and open so many tabs...

---

You can use `gitk [filename]`(GUI) or `git log -p filename`(Command line) to view all history changes of a single file easily.

Source: *[View the change history of a file using Git versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278192/view-the-change-history-of-a-file-using-git-versioning)*

Answer (score 2):

Both Github Desktop and github.com have surprisingly limited capabilities for history diffs.

Option 1 (preferred): migrate to [Atlassian Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/); much better experience overall; integration with JIRA, etc.

Option 2: if you are on Windows - try [Tortoise GIT desktop client](https://tortoisegit.org/download/); has Show Log feature which I find very helpful for side-by-side diffs.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/pomber/git-history a very handy UI tool (and plugin) visualization of file changes through time.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate answer of https://stackoverflow.com/a/56845218/10761353

Answer (score -2):

Checkout out [Little Differ](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/little-differ-for-github/iaempmdmfkjkmfgdfkikfolfalijelhe) in the Google Chrome webstore. It's a Chrome extension that shows a sidebar displaying the commit history of a repository or a file.