# Tracking commits with the GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3

I'm looking to work with the GitHub API, but I'm having trouble finding what I need in the documentation.

There's two things I can't find.

- I see that I can [list all the commits in a repository](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository), but I'm not sure how to get each commit's details without calling the [single commit endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-single-commit) a bunch of times.
  Specifically, the amount of `changes` in each file.
- The other thing I can't seem to figure out is how I can get a webhook/event sent to my application whenever a commit is made on a repository. I've made it to the [webhooks page](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#events), but can't seem to find the event I'm looking for.
  Is what I need even possible? Or am I just missing something in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get [diff for each commits in one go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53591411/6309) with the API.
You can get a [global diff between arbitrary commits with an URL](https://help.github.com/en/articles/comparing-commits-across-time#comparing-commits), or, through the API, [comparing two commits](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits), which returns a diff URL. But that won't track each intermediate commit diff.

Regarding webhook, the event you want is the [push event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent): it will be triggered by any new commit pushed to your repository.