# Tracking specific lines of code between revisions in git / GitHub

Tags: git, github, line-numbers, git-blame

When a line of code is submitted to a git repository, its line number may change in future commits, by code being added or removed above it, while fundamentally still being the same line.

Given a [permalink for a code-snippet](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-permanent-link-to-a-code-snippet/), is there an API that answers the question: Do these lines of code exist in git-revision #12345abc, and if so, what are their line-numbers there (and file-name, because I suppose files can be renamed)?

It feels like this is related to `git blame`, but not exactly.

Comment: Are you looking for [`git log -L`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435343/retrieve-the-commit-log-for-a-specific-line-in-a-file), or are you looking for a GitHub equivalent? The closest GitHub equivalent I'm aware of is the [file history view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952507/can-github-show-the-history-of-changes-made-to-one-file-in-patch-form) (which is more like `git log -p`)

Comment: Also trying to figure out the best way to accomplish this.